# User Management for e-commerce

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, token

I am currently working on an e commerce application.
The application has different users:

1. Customers
2. Merchants
3. Logistics
4. Admin

The current db structure has a different table for each of these user types. And I am working on setting up security for the back-end java based rest-application.

I am stuck on how to implement this. I created the following spring-security file.

1. Created and registered a filter.(authenticationTokenProcessingFilter)
2. In the filter class, I check for the request URLs to identify which DAO I should use to validate the user.

** spring-security.xml**

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
<security:http pattern="/rest/users/**" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" create-session="stateless">
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter"
        position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/users/{userId}/orders/**"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:logout />
</security:http>

<security:http pattern="/rest/admin/**" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" create-session="stateless">
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationAdminFilter"
        position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/admin/**"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:logout />
</security:http>

<security:http pattern="/rest/business/**"
    entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true"
    auto-config="false" create-session="stateless">
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter"
        position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/business/{businessId}/orderItems**"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_MERCHANT')" />
    <security:logout />
</security:http>

<security:http pattern="/rest/merchant/**"
    entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true"
    auto-config="false" create-session="stateless">
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter"
        position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/merchant/**"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_MERCHANT_ADMIN')" />
    <security:logout />
</security:http>



<bean id="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" class="com.resource.security.TokenAuthenticationFilter">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
        <value>/rest/**</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="com.resource.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
</bean>


<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" />
```

**PROBLEMS**

1. If a particular URL has to be invoked by two roles I am not sure how to do it as I validate and assign one role only in the filter. Eg: an admin can access any urls that a customer accesses.

Comment: Just some recommendations: first of all, I would look at using java config vs xml config, it will make life much easier using annotations. You will place both security types on the method and just use some logic to determine which user type is trying to access that part of the system so that your code acts accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple tables to manage multiple users, create a single table for all, then differentiate them using roles. Use ROLE_CUSTOMER, ROLE_MERCHANT, ROLE_ADMIN, and ROLE_LOGISTICS. Then you can use hasRole to define who can access what URL.

Why are you using different tables, If I may ask? I don't quite see the benefit, other than reusing usernames.

Comment: The DB structure is like this and I can't backfill data to a single table.That's the reason I am looking for  a solve to circumvent this situation

Comment: Is it a good idea to create a view based on these 4 tables and use that for querying during auth?

Comment: Try using union on the tables to get a single table that combines all the users. You can make the result a view as @user5118993 suggested. Then make all queries to that table. This is the quick-and-dirty solution at the top of my mind, but there might be problems like duplicate usernames.